Debugger Stops When Clicking on Variables - "Step Over" Button Disabled (In STS 4)
Description
I'm encountering an issue while debugging my application. When I click on certain variables in the variable tab to inspect their values, the debugger unexpectedly stops, and the "Step Over" button becomes disabled. This behavior disrupts my debugging process.
Environment

IDE/Debugger: STS 4
Programming Language: Java 17 Corretto
Operating System: Win 10

Steps to Reproduce

Start debugging the application.
When execution is paused at a breakpoint, click on a variable in the variable tab.
Observe that the debugger stops, and the "Step Over" button is disabled.

Expected Behavior
I expect to be able to inspect the variable's value without interrupting the debugging session or disabling the "Step Over" functionality.
Additional Information

I have checked for any breakpoints set on variable access.
No exceptions are thrown when I click on the variable.
I have reviewed the debugger settings to ensure they are configured correctly.


This isn't a bug reporting system, but does it re-enable when you go back to the Debug View and select a thread or stack frame there? It's likely that the button no longer has any idea what it's supposed to be stepping over once the Variables view has focus and a variable is selected.
